# Add-on giving NoClassDefFoundError in Vaadin

Tags: vaadin, add-on, export-to-pdf

I came across this add-on that converts the screencontent into a PDF file. However, when I add these lines of code:

```
PdfFromComponent factory = new PdfFromComponent();
factory.export(contentcity);
```

I get this error message:

> 'javax.servlet.ServletException: com.vaadin.server.ServiceException:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/itextpdf/text/DocumentException'
>   with root cause:  'com.vaadin.server.ServiceException:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/itextpdf/text/DocumentException'

I Already added the jar file into the library and compiled the widgetset but the error persists. Can someone briefly explain me how to deal with this?

Comment: Which addon is this?

Comment: PDFExport (https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/pdfexport)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the following Maven dependency to your project:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
   <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
   <version>5.5.6</version>
</dependency>
```

For some strange reason the author does not ship a pom file within his addon, so he could not mark this as a dependency.

Comment: I added it to my pom but now i encounter another error :
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/vaadin/terminal/Resource

Comment: What version of Vaadin is this?

Comment: Oh, don't even bother answering. You are using 7 (as you should), but this addon does not support it. Check the left blue column on the site: https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/pdfexport . The file it was missing this time was removed in 7.something Alpha.

Comment: Bad news, sorry. You need to drop this addon, and look for something else.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, the JVM throws a NoClassDefFoundError also when there is more than one version of a class. It could be that you have more than one iText JAR in your classpath. Check if the add-on you are using includes the iText JAR and double-check that you are not including the JAR more than once.

Comment: could you please specify where to find the classpath you mean? Is it the 'maven dependencies', where all the jar files are?